# SQL запрос по максимальному значению в столбце таблицы с учетом других столбцов

Tags: sql

Есть таблица Documents -

| id | general_id | Doc_Type | Doc_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 13 | 1 |
| 2 | 101 | 13 | 2 |
| 3 | 101 | 14 | 1 |
| 4 | 101 | 14 | 2 |
| 5 | 101 | 14 | 3 |
| 6 | 101 | 15 | 1 |
| 7 | 102 | 13 | 1 |
| 8 | 102 | 13 | 2 |

Необходим запрос sql по которому нужно выбрать по каждому general_id и Doc_type строки с максимальной значением в Doc_version.
В результате должно получиться -

| id | general_id | Doc_Type | Doc_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 101 | 13 | 2 |
| 5 | 101 | 14 | 3 |
| 6 | 101 | 15 | 1 |
| 8 | 102 | 13 | 2 |

Есть ли кого-то идеи как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В современных СУБД есть оконная функция row_number, позволяющая пронумеровать строки внутри группы.

Группируем по general_id и doc_type, нумеруем по doc_version по убыванию, и в каждой группе оставляем только первую строку.

Так как в большинстве СУБД row_number нельзя использовать в условии WHERE напрямую, нужно сделать подзапрос и вывести номер строки как новый столбец:

```
SELECT id, general_id, doc_type, doc_version
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, general_id, doc_type, doc_version,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY general_id, doc_type ORDER BY doc_version DESC) AS RN
   FROM Documents
) D
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Очень интересный способ, надо разобраться в этих оконных функциях. К сожалению программка Toad for Oracle в которой я пытаюсь выполнить этот запрос ругается с ошибкой (ORA-30483: функции окна в данном месте запрещены). Попробую сейчас справиться с этой ошибкой!

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, забыл.

Comment: @Beranill, указывайте, пожалуйста, СУБД в тэгах вопроса. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Протестировал ваш вариант, все отлично работает! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
SELECT general_id, Doc_type, max(doc_version) AS Doc_version
FROM Documents
GROUP BY general_id, Doc_type
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш вариант не даст id

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Все работает, но если добавить поле id, то выдает ошибку : "неверно предложение на языке SQL"

Comment: @Beranill увы, id упустил из виду как рабочий столбец. Можно к результату этого запроса приджойнить id из стартовой таблицы по условиям равенства трёх остальных столбцов